# Run a stored procedure with all the variable in declare and retrieving no values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've managed to write my stored procedure, it is running now but no results are retrieved.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SigleEnseigne]
AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @Sigle VARCHAR(150),
            @Enseigne VARCHAR(150),  
            @SigleEnseigne1 VARCHAR(150)

        SELECT  @Sigle = ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') ,
                @Enseigne = ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') ,
                @SigleEnseigne1 = CASE WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%'
                                       THEN '      / '
                                            + ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '')
                                       WHEN ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') = ''
                                            AND ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') = ''
                                       THEN ''
                                       ELSE @Sigle + ' / ' + @Enseigne
                                  END
        FROM    John_Jack

        SELECT @Sigle, @Enseigne, @SigleEnseigne1

    END
```

Yet when I'm running `SELECT * FROM John_Jack`, I do have results.

What I'm doing wrong?

Have I misunderstood something along the way?

I've' checked on the internet but nothing relevant stood out.

Comment: How many records are there in `John_Jack` table ?

Comment: Show your table structure and data. Do you get no records or one record with empy values?

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: 8 rows

Comment: @AndyK: Then use `Top 1 ` clause along with `Order by ` clause to get appropriate record you want.

Comment: @KrishnrajRana Is there a way to retrieve the whole table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing some condition in your select here:

```
SELECT  @Sigle = ...
FROM    John_Jack
```

thus in the case when it is more then one record in `John_Jack` table, your variables assignment will not work as intended: you can't put multiple values from table into variable.

you have either write some filtering condition in `where` clause, or (if you don't care what exactly values you'll get from table) just use something like

```
SELECT  TOP 1
   @Sigle = ...
FROM    John_Jack
```

Or, if you need to retrieve whole table data "reformatted" according to your logic (as you stated in comments) - then just get rid of these variables and rewrite your procedure as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SigleEnseigne]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') as Sigle,
        ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') as Enseigne,
        CASE WHEN Code_Juridique LIKE 'M%'
            THEN '      / '
            + ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '')
            WHEN ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') = ''
            AND ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '') = ''
                    THEN ''
                    ELSE ISNULL(John_Jack.Sigle, '') 
                         + ' / ' + ISNULL(John_Jack.Enseigne, '')
            END as SigleEnseigne1
            FROM    John_Jack
END
```

Comment: Hi @andy-korneyev, thank you. When I'm creating it , I have an error saying **@Sigle** must be declared. Should I still declare the **@Sigle**?